# Return a value based on a time in a SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

I want a query to make which return 1 when the time is in between of 10:00 pm - 5:00 pm. Else it should return 0.

```
Select * from table
```

Comment: What does your table look like? What query have you tried already?

Comment: Case statement? that 10pm to 5pm looks odd, you really meant it that way?

Comment: Could you please add some more details and attemepts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want between 10:00 AM and 5:00 PM, you can use this

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '17:00:00' THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

In this context,

```
Select * from table
```

makes no sense, unless you have a time column and want to evaluate that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query may be it helpful to you.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE TIME(created_at) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '15:00:00'
```

Comment: This wouldn't return 0 in case of out of time